# Pre submission required field validation ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I had such a quick response time and had very helpful comments on my first question so I thought I would bring another issue here.

Currently I have an application that does form validation. My issue is that it only shows the required fields or form validation after submitting. However I want it to show an asterisk or a validation msg next to it until there is some text or the validation requirements have been met.

So when you go to the blank form all required fields should have a message or asterisk, the moment I type or the field requirement is met the message should go away.

I can only get it to do this after the submission.

Here are my relevant code snippets....

**View Code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
   // @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{   
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber};
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

**Model Code**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**Web Config Code**

```
        <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Bundle Config Code**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

As you can tell from the controller there is a little more going on, but for simplicity sake I want to focus on just one field, name.

Comment: Do you enable client side validation?

Comment: @KimHoang Yes I have client side validation on. I am going to update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Unobtrusive Valudation

1) install via nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive/
This will install a bunch of javascript files in our Scripts directory

2) Edit your bundleConfig

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)  
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
}
```

3) You'll need to render the unobtrusive scripts on your page somewhere, with this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

This should get you started.

A full guide on how to do this is here:

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/

Comment: This looks very hopeful thank you, I will test it out after lunch.

Comment: Back at it, I just read through the article I already have all of that setup ....

Comment: I've decided this is as close as I will get without much more code. It does give you validation instantaneously but only after the first submission. So if you submit an empty form then all the messages will react with you in real time, but it's contingent upon that first submission.

Answer (score -1):

Client side validation is done using jquery. Ensure you have jquery and the validate scripts included in your page.

```
<script src=".../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src=".../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does that doesn't do all the work though right? You still have to do something along the lines what said no?